# Swift iBeacon only one beacon got monitored

Tags: ios, parse-platform, ibeacon

I've got 3 beacons on my table, all three have the same UUID but different major and minor numbers. I am expecting to see 3 beacons enter and exit event but only one shows.

I have didEnter and didExit region going and so far, I'm consistently only seeing 1 beacon, the same beacon getting notified when I enter and exit the beacon range.

A list of beacon data are downloaded from our Parse account and I am looping through all of them and telling iOS to monitor the beacon:

```
    func downloadBeacons()
    {
        var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Beacon");

        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                NSLog("Beacons = ", objects!);

                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {

                    for beacon in objects {
                        NSLog("------------------------");
                        NSLog("Beacon UUID = %@", beacon["UUID"] as! NSString);
                        NSLog("Beacon major number = %@", beacon["major"] as! NSString);
                        NSLog("Beacon minor number = %@", beacon["minor"] as! NSString);
                        NSLog("Beacon manufactureID = %@", beacon["manufacturerId"] as! NSString);
                        NSLog("Beacon manufacture = %@", beacon["manufacturer"] as! NSString);

                        var uuid:NSUUID = NSUUID(UUIDString: beacon["UUID"] as! String)!;

                        var majorValue:UInt16 = self.stringToUnsignedInt16(beacon["major"] as! String);
                        var minorValue:UInt16 = self.stringToUnsignedInt16(beacon["minor"] as! String);

                        // start monitoring each beacon?
                        var beaconObj = BeaconModel(name: beacon["manufacturerId"] as! NSString,
                            uuid: uuid,
                            majorValue: majorValue,
                            minorValue: minorValue,
                            manufacturer: beacon["manufacturer"] as! NSString);

                        self.startMonitoringBeaconObj(beaconObj);
                    }

                }
            }
            else {
                NSLog("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)");
            }

        }
    }
```

My startMonitoringBeacon method is below:

```
func startMonitoringBeaconObj(beaconObj:BeaconModel) {
    var beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = self.beaconRegionWithBeaconObj(beaconObj);

    LocationManager.sharedInstance.manager.startMonitoringForRegion(beaconRegion);
    LocationManager.sharedInstance.manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
}
```

This is my helper method:

```
func beaconRegionWithBeaconObj(beaconObj:BeaconModel) -> CLBeaconRegion {

    var beaconRegion:CLBeaconRegion = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: beaconObj.uuid, major: beaconObj.majorValue, minor: beaconObj.minorValue, identifier: beaconObj.manufacturer as! String);

    beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = true;
    beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = true;        

    return beaconRegion;
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Region monitoring is based on UUID so since your UUID is same both `didEnterRegion:` and `didExitRegion:` would be called once. However, beacon ranging would return you all the varieties of beacons with that UUID (different major & minor values).

If you have three beacons in close proximity (as you mentioned all 3 sitting on your table) broadcasting same UUID then the listener would get callback only once in `didEnterRegion`. You can try by keeping three beacons far away and then move the listener. You should see `didEnterRegion` getting called 3 times provided `didExitRegion:` on previous one is called before you enter same region again.

Comment: I'm not asking why `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` is called once, I'm asking why all three of my beacon devices are not reacting to the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion ?

Comment: What do you mean by not reacting to `didEnterRegion `? I have added more explanation in my post.

Comment: I tried moving the other two beacons to the corner of my house so they would be more than 10 metres apart. Only the same one beacon react to my iPhone, the other two doesn't react. They're Kontakt beacons and I've downloaded the Kontakt app, it shows all three beacons having around 90% battery life.

Comment: That too is expected. Region monitoring works with +, - 150m accuracy. If you have seen WWDC video of 2012 where Apple showcased Apple Store customer behaviour, customers gets notified as soon as they are in parking lot. So, even if you have 3 beacons with UUID lying apart >10 m, you still going to find only one beacon. Better use 3 UUID and listen to all three if you really want to test it :)! I hop I made the point clear.

Comment: Not sure what the heck happened or what I did, but somehow all three beacons are working now =/ Weird.